# How to make a SwingWorker Start more than once..?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

As in the image I have created a button called "filter" to filter out a specific data set according to their current status.I used a SwingWorker to retrieve data from the database.The code that I have now works fine. once I click the button it shows the related data. But when I click it again with different status, it does not show the required data.I am reading that the doingBackground method will only be executed once. Is there a way to fire it off again..??

[image]

Comment: `I have created a button called "filter" to filter out a specific data set according to their current status` - Do you need to keep going back to the database each time? Depending on volume of data it may be easier to load all the data into the TableModel and then filter the model. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't restart a SwingWorker, and what's more, you don't want to. Per the [SwingWorker API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html):

> SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once. Executing a SwingWorker more than once will not result in invoking the doInBackground method twice.

Your solution is to create a new SwingWorker instance within your button's ActionListener and execute it; do this, and you'll likely be fine.